# Probability density function with a single smooth curve

Tags: python, matplotlib, probability-density

This is something I don't completely understand. 
I'm trying to plot a probability density function using this [scipy function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html). How do I smooth this graph to have a single curve?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
Z = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=1000)
from scipy.stats import norm
plt.plot(Z, norm.pdf(Z, Z.mean(), Z.std()))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort your list and then plot it:

```
Z = np.sort(Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do `scatter` instead of `plot`:

```
plt.scatter(Z, norm.pdf(Z, Z.mean(), Z.std()),s=1)
```

Output:

[image]